# Criteria Api: Create null value with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there a better way to create a SQL `null` value with `CriteriaBuilder` than

```
criteriaBuilder.quot(criteriaBuilder.literal(0), criteriaBuilder.literal(0))
```

?

Comment: Have you tried with [CriteriaBuilder#nullLiteral](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#nullLiteral%28java.lang.Class%29)?

Comment: `criteriaBuilder.nullLiteral(Integer.class)` works!

Comment: Great. I am going to add the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the method [`CriteriaBuilder#nullLiteral()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#nullLiteral%28java.lang.Class%29) which does exactly that. Since you need a null Integer, use it with Integer Class:

```
Expression<Integer> expr = criteriaBuilder.nullLiteral(Integer.class);
```